# Python - First line reading CSV not in order

Tags: python, pandas, csv, counter

When reading a CSV with a list games in a single column, the game in the first/top row is displayed out of order, like so:

```
                        Fatal Labyrinth™
0                            Beat Hazard
1                             Dino D-Day
2                 Anomaly: Warzone Earth
3                        Project Zomboid
4           Avernum: Escape From the Pit
```

..with the code being:

```
my_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\kosta\list.csv', encoding='utf-16', delimiter='=')
print(my_data)
```

Fatal Labyrinth is, I suppose, not indexed. Adding 'index_col=0' lists each game, like so:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [Beat Hazard, Dino D-Day, more games etc...]
```

But this does not help, as the endgame here is to count each game and determine the most common, but when doing:

```
counts = Counter(my_data)
dictTime = dict(counts.most_common(3))
for key in dictTime:
    print(key)
```

..all I'm getting back is:

```
Fatal Labyrinth™
```

Thank you :)

Comment: I think you want to add argumet `header=None` in `read_csv`

Comment: Thanks Erfan. That does help a bit. The same list now starts with 0 and counting only shows the 0.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add "**names=**" parameter when you read the CSV file.

```py
my_data = pd.read_csv('test.csv',  delimiter='=', names=['Game_Name'])  # Game_Name is given as column name
print(my_data)
```

```
                      Game_Name
0              Fatal Labyrinth™
1                   Beat Hazard
2                    Dino D-Day
3        Anomaly: Warzone Earth
4               Project Zomboid
5  Avernum: Escape From the Pit
```

Also **value_counts()** can be used on the dataframe to find the frequency of the value.

```py
(my_data.Game_Name.value_counts(ascending=False)).head(3)  # Top three most frequent value
```

```
Project Zomboid           1
Anomaly: Warzone Earth    1
Beat Hazard               1
Name: Game_Name, dtype: int64
```

In case, you need to get the top game name by its frequency,

```py
(my_data.Game_Name.value_counts()).head(1).index[0]
```

```
'Project Zomboid'
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps. Is there a way to not list the corresponding number of times the game appears? i.e. the in your comment, 'Project Zomboid' appears once, but can I get rid of the 1?

Comment: You can use "head(1).index[0]"  to the command. Added to the main answer.